# HTML/Jquery can't get data from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I writing a web site that can show a data table depends on the name you click.
First, this is my main page:`random.html`

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="comp1">comp1</a>
<a href="#" id="comp2">comp2</a>
<a href="#" id='comp3'>comp3</a>

<div></div>

<script  src="script/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script  src="script/random.js"></script>
<script src="script/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

I set click() on each `a` to get their `id` and send to PHP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bk.php",
            data: {"name" : $(this).attr('id')}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $('div').empty();
              $('div').load('booking.html');
       });

    });
});
```

and this is my PHP:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("") ;
    if(!$con){
        die('could not connect:'.mysqli_erro());
    }

   $id = $_POST['name'];
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `$id`");
   $row =1;


   while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {
       for($i = 1; $i<=18; $i++){
           if($data[$i]=='Booked!'){
               $str = $row.$i;
               $array[]=$str;

           }
       }
       $row++;
   }


   $count=count($array);

   echo json_encode($array);
```

in the `booking.html` file, I use another .js file which also uses this `bk.php` file to get the data and fetch it into the table. But when my table was printed out, there was nothing in it. What I'm saying here is both `random.html` and `booking.html` they are using the same `bk.php` file and I think, may be when `booking.html` is loaded, that `bk.php` is reloaded and that `$id` becomes null so I get nothing. Is there any way to store and pass an variable from page to page ? I've been looking answer but none was successful

Comment: Does your PHP file actually work? Is `mysqli_erro()` a typo?

Comment: 1) In your JQuery AJAX method, write your returned variables into id's  already on the page since you're getting JSON back (or a chunk of HTML into an empty place holder), but don't receive JSON back & then write booking.html into the empty div upon successful completion of AJAX response.
2) When debugging AJAX problems, it is helpful to enter the URL of your script that is producing the JSON in your browser, hit "enter" & then look at what it is outputting.  You can see if your client JS is receiving what you think it is.
3) You seem to be counting things you don't use in your php loops

Comment: @putande: my PHP file can work, I tried it with seperated file, even with `mysqli_erro()`.

Comment: @AndrewKoper: I don't receive the data in this main page, I receive it  in `booking.html`, of course my Json does that. Every thing works fine, but the only problem I have that the `booking.html` can't get what in the php file

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your PHP:

```
die('could not connect:'.mysqli_erro());
```

should be:

```
die('could not connect:'.mysqli_error());
```

**EDIT:**

How come you use `booking.html`, seperately to load the data? Can't you just get `bk.php` to generate the table for you depending on the passed $id? That way `bk.php` won't be loaded twice and you won't have unnecessary Javascript.

Also, off-topic I notice you are using the $id to select a table name, this is bad practise as the variables aren't escaped, so if possible use prepared statements to avoid the danger of SQL injections.

Comment: ok, thank you, I didn't think of generating table in PHP, thank you